# Is it possible to have priority inversion with two processes?

Tags: operating-system

The usual example gives three processes, but shouldn't it be possible with only two processes?

Let us assume we have two processes, p3 and p1. p3's priority is less than p1. p3 is currently in the critical section using a resource which p1 will need. p1 comes along, and p3 gets preempted by p1. But, p3 was holding a resource which p1 needed to run.

Isn't this an example of priority inversion with 2 processes?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not.  `p1` will just block when it tries to acquire the resource, which will allow `p3` to run again, finish using the resource, and relinquish it, thereby unblocking `p1`.

Wikipedia's [example of a priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion#Example_of_a_priority_inversion) is a good reference that describes why three tasks are required.

Comment: Wait you are right. I overlooked this fact and I wasn't thinking straight. The example I gave is actually just a case of being blocked and (maybe) deadlocked.